# Error al instalar react-native link (NativeBase)

Tags: react-native

Luego de instalar NativeBase en el directorio del proyecto con:

`yarn add native-base` (todo ok hasta aqui)

Lo que sigue de acuerdo a la documentación es instalar:

`react-native link`

Sin embargo me arroja el siguiente aviso:

`zsh: command not found: react-native` (react-native si se encuentra en las dependencias del package.json)

Comment: intenta reiniciar el equipo y verifica este link a ver si resuelves el problema: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37193032/4717133

Answer (score 0):

- https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup
- https://docs.nativebase.io/docs/GetStarted.html

  ```
  Globally installed node >= 6.0
  Globally installed npm >= 4.0
  Globally installed React Native CLI which allow you to easily create and initialize projects.
  ```

Hay que instalar Node.js, luego o instalar Expo, o usar la cmd de react (npx) que ya trae react-native

> React Native has a built-in command line interface, which you can use
> to generate a new project. You can access it without installing
> anything globally using npx, which ships with Node.js.

Comment: Gracias Carina, npx fue la solucion, solo me falto colocar npx delante, de esta manera: npx react-native link   ( y se instalo correctamente)